# Date time Module

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.4

```
start_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    new_date=start_date+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Given that I start my code by impoting datetime, why do I need to write datetime twice in the first line of code and only once in the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how imports work in Python. By writing `import datetime` you are importing a *module*. This module in turn has *classes* `datetime` and `timedelta`.

It is pretty common for a module to have its most important class be called the same thing. Another way to import in Python makes the relationship between modules and their classes more clear:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
```

Then you can call the class directly like

```
new_date = start_date + timedelta(days=1)
```